# Why is my roof leaking when it isn't raining?

Tags: leak, roof

I've just moved house last week and today have noticed a drip in my dining room. What's odd is that it isn't raining - in fact, today is the first warm day of the year.

The "water" is a brown colour, but doesn't seem to have an odor. Moreover, I'm also noticing drips from the roof line on the outside of this part of the house.

It's a single story extension without plumbing, so I don't think it's a leaky pipe. The gutters are bone dry and there's no standing water on the (flat, leaded) roof.

What could be causing this? And how would I solve it?

Comment: Do you have any AC ducts running in the area and have you been running  the AC unit?

Comment: Condensation is the usual suspect given no plumbing and no rain. Depending how cold it's been, possibly frozen condensation melting.

Comment: @JACK Good idea, but no - no AC in this house.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Hello again. Condensation between the lead and the timbers? Could be, I suppose. Not had any frost recently, so probably not ice melting.

Comment: Condensation from humid air settling. Have you had any dew in the morning?

Comment: Do you have any access to the attic/area above the ceiling?

Comment: @FreeMan It was a lovely crisp morning followed by an unseasonably warm day. Not sure if there was any dew per se, but it was the right conditions for it certainly.

Comment: @GregNickoloff There's no attic area really - just a flat ceiling inside and a flat roof on top. Single-digit inches of thickness all told I reckon.

Comment: @TomWright - That may indicate water collected under the roof coating? Is there more than one layer of roofing material? How much water are you seeing all together?

Comment: @GregNickoloff It's dripping from a few points (one inside, a few around the outside edge) at a rate of about one drip every 30 seconds. Not a huge volume by any means.

Comment: Sometimes a leak collects in insulation or builds up until it finds a hole to drip through. I rain a few days ago may have collected enough water to finally start dripping.

Comment: This is the point where I just bite the bullet and cut an opening in the ceiling drywall. You  just want to be able to see how extensive the moisture is and its source so start small - you can always make it bigger as needed. There are so many different things that might cause this it's probably the only way that you'll be able to identify the problem with any certainty.

Comment: By the sounds of it, condensation is the most likely culprit. If someone wants to add an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @TomWright but if condensation is the source, you still need to figure out why there's enough "free" airspace somewhere and why there is no system set up to drain that area. Otherwise the problem will continue and your ceiling may crumble (or mold will set up in some interstitial place, which is really bad news.

Comment: Check for coaxial cabling from an antenna, this can act as a pipe, rusting the water as it goes. My cat got unfairly blamed for urinating on the back of the TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a bunch of builders take a look and the consensus was that the timbers in the roof structure were "sweating" in the heat. This was apparently caused by a combination of the outer roofing material (lead, in our case) not being 100% water tight, and the void above the ceiling not being adequately vented.

We had the roof replaced, including new beam. The problem hasn't recurred.

Comment: Good point, I didn't mention the new bleed vents above the line of the ceiling. My gut tells me that the new roof is the main driver here though - preventing water ingress in the first place means less moisture to vent.

Comment: That information would be better presented in your answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

When water leaks through ceiling it makes drywall weak. Recently I replaced leaky hot water pipe in the house. A big area of ceiling was damaged. Not sure how big or a small ceiling portion is affected in your case. I would first make a small hole with a nail or at least 1/4” drill. If water is accumulated and comes out faster or more you may have to cut 12x12” piece of ceiling. (I would start there.)

Let us know what is your finding. Making hole or cutting small portion of ceiling was suggested based on your info.